# Best Way to Retrieve MetaData from Mp3s In Android

Tags: android, mp3, metadata

I've been working on a small media player app for Android. I'm having some trouble retrieving the meta data from the music files. I've been using the **MediaMetadataRetriever**, but it has proved to be quite troublesome. Does anyone know of a better way to go about this? If so how would one implement such method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `JAudioTagger`, which you can find [here](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). It supports (basically) every version of ID3, so you're covered even for old files with outdated metadata. Pretty good (and easy) solution. Other options include [mp3agic](http://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) and [entagged](http://entagged.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you. I will explore these options.

Comment: I tried using this library, but it seems the latest version is incompatible with Dalvik JVM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247862 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488236

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the metadata from the Android database, [using the code here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-beginners/SasjFZ5k0yc%5B1-25%5D). Just change the [managedquery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) to something like:

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " == ?";
cursor = this.managedQuery(media,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        new String[] {file.getCanonicalPath().toString()},
                        null);
```

This returns a cursor to the metadata of `file`. (Author, Title, duration etc.)