# Android - Set and Get metadata from file

Tags: android, android-file

How to set and get the metadata like author, modified date etc of a file?

Comment: Reading the metadata is doable, see [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542519/best-way-to-retrieve-metadata-from-mp3s-in-android/11945428#11945428). I would also like to know if there is a similar way to set the data in the mediastore.