# Validation by annotations?

Tags: java, android

is there any similar to Annotation based JSF/Hibernate validation für Android?
Or do I always have to 'manually' validate each input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think he was referring to [jsr-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) and its reference implementation [Hibernate-Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) which could be used in Android (at least I managed to use 4.2.0.Final) if you get rid of a java.beans.Introspector dependency.

See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-779
and [Is there a work around for the Android error "Unable to resolve virtual method java/beans/PropertyDescriptor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488236/is-there-a-work-around-for-the-android-error-unable-to-resolve-virtual-method-j)

Answer (score -1):

What u mean by Hibernate Viladation Hibernate is different thing it is just an ORM and JSF is MVC;
you can use Regular Expressions to deal with them or use

> android:maxLines="5"
>       android:maxHeight="5"
>       android:maxLength="5"
>       android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

or use these properties

Comment: I meant the Validation by annotations. If there is some in Android?