# Android Studio @Valid annotation not working

Tags: android-studio, annotations

I am using a `@Valid` annotation in a section of my code in Android Studio and it is being marked in red as en error.

After some research I have found that `@Valid` belongs to something called `JSR-303`.

I would like to know how to add this to my android project, I am having problems to find the compile or the package that needs to be added.

If that helps, the following line is also being marked in red:

`import javax.validation.Valid;`

Im my `build.gradle` I have:

```
compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsr 303 and the reference implementation Hibernate-Validator can be implemented in Android if you can get rid of a java.beans.Introspector dependency.

Please have a look at [Is there a work around for the Android error "Unable to resolve virtual method java/beans/PropertyDescriptor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488236/is-there-a-work-around-for-the-android-error-unable-to-resolve-virtual-method-j) and
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-779

Source : [Validation by annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628627/validation-by-annotations)