# VerrifyError with Guice on Android maven project

Tags: android, maven, guice, android-maven-plugin

So I'm trying to get Guice to run in my android maven project and bundle in a 3rd party module. It runs fine in the normal junittest that does a test injection, but fails on the VM with the logcat message attached below.

What I can't understand is that there are numerous reports of Guice working fine on android . Despite this, my code seems to be failing on getBeanInfo() being called from the Guice injector. It seems I'm not the only one having this error.

[Is there a work around for the Android error "Unable to resolve virtual method java/beans/PropertyDescriptor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488236/is-there-a-work-around-for-the-android-error-unable-to-resolve-virtual-method-j)

So I have a couple of questions. Is the reason Guice isn't working for me, because some functionality is being invoked by my 3rd party module that would fail everywhere but isn't common? Is there a way to get more info out of Guice as to what specifically is triggering the offending getBeanInfo()? Are there work arounds? What avenues are available to me for further debugging.

The solution must be maven compatible, as answers to a similar question about tweaking eclipse settings for similar problems can't apply. [Getting "Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247862/getting-caused-by-java-lang-verifyerror)
(not that I got much mileage here anyway).

I think that all relevant files were processed by dx by the android maven plugin, as dependency:tree shows all relevant project at scope "compile", but I'm no expert here.

```
03-05 00:57:34.529: I/dalvikvm(2295): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-05 00:57:34.568: I/dalvikvm(2295): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-05 00:57:35.059: I/dalvikvm(2295): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295): Could not load Finalizer in its own class loader. Loading Finalizer in the current class loader instead. As a result, you will not be able to garbage collect this class loader. To support reclaiming this class loader, either resolve the underlying issue, or move Google Collections to your system class path.
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295): java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Finalizer.class
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.getBaseUrl(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:269)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.loadFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:253)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.loadFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:175)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:100)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$QueueHolder.(MapMaker.java:787)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$WeakEntry.(MapMaker.java:946)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$Strength$1.newEntry(MapMaker.java:312)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.newEntry(MapMaker.java:498)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.newEntry(MapMaker.java:419)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2029)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.hasAnnotations(Annotations.java:116)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.isScopeAnnotation(Annotations.java:124)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.ScopeBindingProcessor.visit(ScopeBindingProcessor.java:40)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.ScopeBindingProcessor.visit(ScopeBindingProcessor.java:30)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.spi.ScopeBinding.acceptVisitor(ScopeBinding.java:59)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:55)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:165)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at za.co.mambo.cherrylist.android.CherryListActivity.onCreate(CherryListActivity.java:27)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 00:57:35.098: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(2295):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 00:57:35.108: I/dalvikvm(2295): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-05 00:57:35.338: D/dalvikvm(2295): GC_CONCURRENT freed 391K, 4% free 12676K/13127K, paused 8ms+5ms
03-05 00:57:35.418: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-05 00:57:35.418: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-05 00:57:35.418: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-05 00:57:35.418: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-05 00:57:35.418: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-05 00:57:35.428: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;)
03-05 00:57:35.438: I/dalvikvm(2295): Could not find method java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo, referenced from method com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.getPropertiesHelper
03-05 00:57:35.438: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8989: Ljava/beans/Introspector;.getBeanInfo (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/beans/BeanInfo;
03-05 00:57:35.438: D/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
03-05 00:57:35.458: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1373 (Ljava/beans/IntrospectionException;)
03-05 00:57:35.458: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x4e
03-05 00:57:35.458: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY:  rejected Lcom/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$ReflectUtils;.getPropertiesHelper (Ljava/lang/Class;ZZ)[Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;
03-05 00:57:35.458: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x004e
03-05 00:57:35.458: W/dalvikvm(2295): VFY:  rejected Lcom/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$ReflectUtils;.getPropertiesHelper (Ljava/lang/Class;ZZ)[Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;
03-05 00:57:35.458: W/dalvikvm(2295): Verifier rejected class Lcom/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$ReflectUtils;
03-05 00:57:35.488: D/AndroidRuntime(2295): Shutting down VM
03-05 00:57:35.498: W/dalvikvm(2295): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-05 00:57:35.508: I/dalvikvm(2295): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-05 00:57:35.548: I/dalvikvm(2295): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{za.co.mambo.cherrylist.android/za.co.mambo.cherrylist.android.CherryListActivity}: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$ReflectUtils
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295): Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$ReflectUtils
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:133)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at za.co.mambo.cherrylist.android.CherryListActivity.onCreate(CherryListActivity.java:27)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     ... 11 more
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$ReflectUtils
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:207)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:53)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:153)
03-05 00:57:35.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2295):     at com.google.inject.internal
03-05 00:57:36.178: I/dalvikvm(2295): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-05 00:57:36.188: I/dalvikvm(2295): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-05 00:57:36.530: I/dalvikvm(2295): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-05 00:57:36.538: I/dalvikvm(2295): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Hey, got any solution?

Comment: I posted the question an hour ago, and been attacking it for a good couple of hours... so no.

Comment: Hey Just look at this https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/OSGi  This is only possible when the types involved are not package-private (because by definition package-private types are not visible from other classloaders). If you attempt to use AOP on package-private types while running inside an OSGi container you will see the following exception:

Comment: Thanx. Seems like I have some reading to do.

Comment: This seems to have been resolved in Guice 4.0 beta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718082/java-io-filenotfoundexception-com-google-inject-internal-util-finalizer-class/19017060#19017060

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dalvik vm does not support aspected oriented programming so you can not use the plain JVM Guice. You have to use the no_aop version.

With a Maven build use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
</dependency>
```

to get the no_aop jar into your build and apk.

Of course you can also look at using RoboGuice.

Comment: Thanx! Subra referred to this in the comments above, but seemed unsure of the solution. Was thinking of replacing Guice with Dagger and getting the benefit of precompilation, but your solution is an easier first step. Will mark as correct as soon as I've tried it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference. This is also the case when using Google Collections (guava library). Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have same behavior but I've downloaded guice 3.0 no_aop directly from roboguice site